# MVC3 summing in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, math

I know i will be shouted out for putting logic into the view but I need to in this case.

basically I have 3 ViewBag values which are all intergers, (in fact they are counts from linq queries). I need to sum these so the result can be displayed on my view where they can be accessed. How do i go about doing this. I have tried using @Html.Raw() then performing a calc but this did not work.

**NOTE SOLUTION :: I found the solution and added it in the comment below for others who have the same issue.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Answer is

```
@(ViewBag.Result1 + ViewBag.Result2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare variables right on the page, if you need to.  (Though, as you mentioned, this is the not the best place to do this.)

```
@{
    var numOne = (int)ViewBag.MyFirstNumber;
    var numTwo = (int)ViewBag.MySecondNumber;
    var total = numOne + numTwo;
}

<p>Total: @total</p>
```